# How to send special characters in request parameters in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How to handle special characters in request parameters? Here is my controller:

```
@Scope("request")
@RestController
public class GetOperatorSeries{
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getOperatorSeries(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value = "mobno") long mobno,
            @RequestParam(value = "sourceType") String sourceType,
            @RequestParam(value = "responseType") String responseType)
{

}
```

For example if I use any special characters in request param then it do not read it, like if I am sending "sourceType= @$abc" then it would read it as null or empty. But I want that it should read special characters also.

Comment: Use `%24` instead of `$` in the URL you are accessing.

Comment: @ Andy Turner if end user enters  any special character then how would i handle it

Comment: If the user enters malformed (e.g. unescaped) parameters, you don't have to handle it. That's a problem on their end because they're not following the protocol.

Comment: Actually i am writing a webservice in spring where i have to handle this situation, so if there is any way in coding part where we can handle this then please let me know

Comment: @Andy Turner Actually i am writing a webservice in spring where i have to handle this situation, so if there is any way in coding part where we can handle this then please let me know

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode your request params.

Check this link for a list  : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

and this to convert back and forth : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but actually the scenario is little different. I am writing a webservice in spring where i have to handle if any end user enters special characters in url. So, if there is any way in coding part where we can handle this then please let me know

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but actually the scenario is little different. I am writing a webservice in spring where i have to handle if any end user enters special characters in url. So, if there is any way in coding part where we can handle this then please let me know

Comment: Hey @AnshSethi were you able to resolve this issue? Am facing the same thing

Comment: Hi @user3681970 were you able to solve this issue? i am also facing the same issue here where i have to take special chars like % in web service REST API