# @Request Param truncating

Tags: mongodb, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to delete documents from MongoDB by Id, the Id is a "Sting url": `

```
@Document(collection="Topic")
public class Topic {    

@Id
private String url;`
```

the problem is when i try to delete :`

```
 @GetMapping("/deletetopic")
 public String deleteTopic(@RequestParam String id, Model model) {
    topicServic.deleteTopic(id);
    model.addAttribute("topics", topicServic.getAllTopics());
    return "/bonjour";`
```

From my JSP /bonjour : `

```
<td><a href="deletetopic?id=${topic.url}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-
trash"></span></a></td>`
```

the "@RequesParam Strin id"  does not consist all the URL .. knowing that a url is tooooo long and i only get the 31 first Characters;

Example : A url id : "https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwjLiL2wz-PVAhWBahoKHUwKAQcQFghLMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdevlog.cnrs.fr%2F_media%2Fjdev2015%2Fjdev2015_t6_stephanederaco_springboot-0150703.pdf%3Fid%3Djdev2015%253At6.a07%26cache%3Dcache&usg=AFQjCNFC0lGyd-FSpcr7jwbToTs_EJLo "

if i add this : System.out.println(id); `

```
@GetMapping("/deletetopic")
public String deleteTopic(@RequestParam String id, Model model) {
    System.out.println(id);
    topicServic.deleteTopic(id);
    model.addAttribute("topics", topicServic.getAllTopics());
    return "/bonjour";

}`
```

I only get this as url id : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t 
And there's no document with that id so nothing happens

Any solution plz ?!
Thanks for ur help :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that it's not too short. The `String` got, chopped off where the special character starts since your URL is not encoded. A similar question : [How to send special characters in request parameters in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992342/how-to-send-special-characters-in-request-parameters-in-spring)